# Failures to set up cross compiling for Nvidia Pegasus aarch64

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to set up cross compiling for Nvidia Pegasus aarch64, but I couldn't clear this error out:
I'm not sure what the problem is. Am I missing some compiler_flags or cxx_builtin_include_directory?

Any help or pointer is much appreciated!

````
.dazelrc not detected, or running in a container, starting bazel
bazelisk is installed, starting up bazel
INFO: Invocation ID: 23bd7eb6-5784-43bd-b3da-a028b8e5517c
INFO: Analysed target //experimentals/examples/gflags:example (2 packages loaded, 10787 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
SUBCOMMAND: # //experimentals/examples/gflags:example [action 'Compiling experimentals/examples/gflags/example.cc']
(cd /home/liangzou/.cache/bazel/_bazel_liangzou/dc52644b6b18e9f28b52bbe6947685bc/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/home/liangzou/.local/bin:/home/liangzou/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/liangzou/bin:/home/liangzou/gitdotnet/ \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  toolchain/gcc.sh -DVIBRANTE '-DVIBRANTE_PDK_BUILD=1' '-DVIBRANTE_PDK_DECIMAL=5010601' '-DVIBRANTE_PDK_MAJOR=5' '-DVIBRANTE_PDK_MINOR=1' '-DVIBRANTE_PDK_PATCH=6' '-DVIBRANTE_PDK_VERSION="5.1.6.1"' -DVIBRANTE_V5L -D_GLFW_USE_CONFIG_H '-isystem external/nvidia_pdk2' '-std=c++11' -MD -MF bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/experimentals/examples/gflags/_objs/example/example.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/experimentals/examples/gflags/_objs/example/example.pic.o' -fPIC -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/genfiles -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin -iquote external/gflags_git -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/genfiles/external/gflags_git -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/external/gflags_git -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/genfiles/external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/external/bazel_tools -isystem external/gflags_git/include -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/genfiles/external/gflags_git/include -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/external/gflags_git/include -isystem external/gflags_git/src -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/genfiles/external/gflags_git/src -isystem bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/external/gflags_git/src -c experimentals/examples/gflags/example.cc -o bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/experimentals/examples/gflags/_objs/example/example.pic.o)
ERROR: /home/liangzou/gitreview/deepmap/deepmap-base/experimentals/examples/gflags/BUILD:1:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//experimentals/examples/gflags:example':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'experimentals/examples/gflags/example.cc':
  '/home/liangzou/nvidia/nvidia_sdk/DRIVE_Software_10.0_Linux_OS_DDPX/DRIVEOS/toolchains/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc/usr/include/stdc-predef.h'
  '/home/liangzou/nvidia/nvidia_sdk/DRIVE_Software_10.0_Linux_OS_DDPX/DRIVEOS/toolchains/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7.3.1/iostream'
  '/home/liangzou/nvidia/nvidia_sdk/DRIVE_Software_10.0_Linux_OS_DDPX/DRIVEOS/toolchains/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7.3.1/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h'
  '/home/liangzou/nvidia/nvidia_sdk/DRIVE_Software_10.0_Linux_OS_DDPX/DRIVEOS/toolchains/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7.3.1/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h'
  '/home/liangzou/nvidia/nvidia_sdk/DRIVE_Software_10.0_Linux_OS_DDPX/DRIVEOS/toolchains/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc/usr/include/features.h'
  '/home/liangzou/nvidia/nvidia_sdk/DRIVE_Software_10.0_Linux_OS_DDPX/DRIVEOS/toolchains/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h'
  '/home/liangzou/nvidia/nvidia_sdk/DRIVE_Software_10.0_Linux_OS_DDPX/DRIVEOS/toolchains/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc/usr/include/bits/wordsize.h'
  '/home/liangzou/nvidia/nvidia_sdk/DRIVE_Software_10.0_Linux_OS_DDPX/DRIVEOS/toolchains/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc/usr/include/bits/long-double.h'```
````

Answer (score 1):

`cxx_builtin_include_directory` is the solution to this. If you just add all of `/home/liangzou/nvidia/nvidia_sdk/DRIVE_Software_10.0_Linux_OS_DDPX/DRIVEOS/toolchains/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu` then it should avoid all of those errors.

It's hard to be more specific without seeing the relevant parts of your toolchain configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
     compiler_flag: "-no-canonical-prefixes"
     compiler_flag: "-fno-canonical-system-headers"
```

I got the flags from this page: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4605